# how to use maps inside the fragment

Tags: android, google-maps

i can show plain guide in inside part i have to add marker to specific geolocation

```
<fragment  
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  />
```

I don't did anything in java code however i extended my class with Fragment

Comment: you can use [mapView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapview) inside `fragment's layout`

Comment: can u explain how to do that kaushik

Answer (score 1):

> Don't forget to add google-play-service-lib as a library project and
>   it should sharing the same workspace of your project

Java code

```
public class SomeFragment extends Fragment {

    MapView mapView;
    GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.some_layout, container, false);

        // Gets the MapView from the XML layout and creates it
        mapView = (MapView) v.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Gets to GoogleMap from the MapView and does initialization stuff
        map = mapView.getMap();
        map.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Needs to call MapsInitializer before doing any CameraUpdateFactory calls
        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(this.getActivity());
        } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Updates the location and zoom of the MapView
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(43.1, -87.9), 10);
        map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        mapView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="your_key"/>

       <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Edit:** After your edit new question arise.
After initializing map check if it is not *null* from [**`official documentation`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html)

```
if(map != null)
{
   Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
     .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
     .title("San Francisco")
     .snippet("Population: 776733"));
}
```

Comment: already added all its displaying map with default view i want to change default view and i need to add marker

Comment: what r u using `MapView` or `SupportMapFragment`

Comment: first used MapView and then i changed to SupportMapFragment

Comment: when i use mapview it showing error in graphical layout like this **The following classes could not be instantiated:**

Answer (score 0):

In your layout, replace your code  with this one :

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    </RelativeLayout>
```

and in your code :

```
private SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment;
private GoogleMap   map;

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    FragmentManager fm = getChildFragmentManager();
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (supportMapFragment == null) {
        supportMapFragment = SupportMapFragment.newInstance();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.map, supportMapFragment).commit();
    }
}    


@Override 
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ...
    map = supportMapFragment.getMap();
    ...
}
```

Comment: it showing error cannot convert from fragment to supportfragment

Comment: If you don't use Android support v4 then in the code you must change SupportMapFragment by MapFragment.